# How to use ruby-pg with async gem in Rails

Tags: ruby, postgresql, nonblocking

With the new PR https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/pull/397 in ruby-pg, it seems that we could use non-blocking methods with `async` gems in Ruby 3.0. Could we have one example to show the non-blocking way?